# How many ways can I put down two indistinguishable pieces on an ordinary $8 \times 8$ chessboard if they must either be in the same row or column?

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

I am a student in middle school and I was wondering if anyone could help me with the following problem:

How many ways can I put down two indistinguishable pieces on an ordinary $8\times 8$ chessboard, if the pieces must either be in the same row or be in the same column?

I think there would be 64 options for the first piece since it can go anywhere on the chessboard, but I'm not sure about the second piece.

Comment: Once the first piece is there how many places are there for the second? (That number won't depend on where the first piece is.). You can check your reasoning if you work out the answer for the $2 \times 2$ chessboard. You may find a surprise. Do the $3 \times 3$.

Comment: The second piece can be in the same row or same column, which is 14 spaces.  Because of interchangeability, you must divide by 2, since every pair you want will turn up twice.

Comment: What is indistinguishable pieces supposed to mean?

Comment: @Zebrafish it is *incredibly* common in these types of problems.  Any arrangement is considered to be the "same" arrangement as another if we swap the positions of two or more "indistinguishable" objects (*indistinguishable here meaning that we cannot tell the difference between them.  they are for all intents and purposes identical*).  Consider a small example where we have two balls, a blue ball and a red ball and we line them up.  The arrangement blue-red is considered different than red-blue.  However, if the balls were both red and indistinguishable, there is only the arrangement red-red.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let's choose one of the two possibilities: either the same row OR the same column. They can't be both because then the two pieces would be the same. There are $16$ total rows and columns.

Next, given a single row/column, we choose two squares out of that specific row/column.

There are 8 squares in that row/column, and we want two of them for a total of $\binom{8}{2}$ or $28$.

Thus, the final answer is $$\text{number of ways to choose a row/column}\times\text{number of ways to choose the squares} $$ $$= 28\cdot 16 = 448$$

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your response!

Answer (score 1):

The first piece can go in any of the $64$ squares. The second piece can then be in any of $14$ positions, since there are $7$ unoccupied squares in the row of the first piece, as well as $7$ unoccupied squares in the column of the first piece. This would seem to give us $64\cdot 14$ choices for the placement of the two pieces. However, order doesn't matter (we said the pieces are indistinguishable), so the actual number of choices is $(64\cdot 14)/2$, which is $\boxed{448}$.